# Why will this Google apps script only work if I hard-code the range?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, columnsorting

I need to make a few sheets in a google doc stay continuously sorted by the first column (a timestamp). That seems easy enough, and my script works, but only if I hard-code range as shown below...I am tryin to figure out why it doesn't work when I use getLastRow() & getLastColumn() to give he range...see commented-out code below. If I uncomment it, this code no longer works. Why?

````
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:Z99";
  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy && /^Form\sResponses/.test(sheet.getSheetName())){  
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    /* WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK -- var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 
sheet.getLastColumn()-1); */
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy , ascending:false});
  };
};```
````

Comment: Unfortunately, although from your question, I'm not sure about the max row and max column of your situation, I think that the spells of `getMaxRow()` and `MaxColumn()` are not correct. When those are modified to `getMaxRows()` and `getMaxColumns()`, respectively, what result will you get? Or you might want to use the last row and last column like `sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()-1)`?

Comment: Good catch, but that is not the problem...I just made the typo in the comment. It doesn't work with either getMaxRows()/Columns() or getLastRow()/Column().

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue from `It doesn't work with either getMaxRows()/Columns() or getLastRow()/Column().`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, can you provide the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to confirm the issue.

Comment: Welcome. As @Tanaike has suggested, it's always better to give more information than less. For example: "it doesn't work when I use getLastRow() & getLastColumn() to give the range" - well, in what way doesn't it work; tell us what range DO you get? Have you tried troubleshooting, insert this row after you declare the range: `Logger.log("range = "+range.getA1Notation());` then view the log and see what range is being referenced.

Comment: `var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()-1);` Why do you deduct "1" from `sheet.getLastColumn()`. It would seem  more logical to deduct it from getLastRow, since it looks like you have a header in row #1. So I would try `var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn());`.

Comment: THanks Tedinoz, I will try that troubleshooting you suggested. 

Deducting 1 from .getLastColumn was a mistake...you're right it makes sense to deduct from row.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach:

Using the functions `.getLastColumn()` and `.getLastRow()` you will get respectively the positions of the last column and row that have content. 
You can use these position to build your range dynamically with the function `.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`.

Since you want to obtain the range "A2:Z99" this will translate in: `.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn())`;

### Solution:

```
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var columnToSortBy = 1;
//var tableRange = "A2:Z99";
if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy && /^Form\sResponses/.test(sheet.getSheetName())){  
   //var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
   var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()); // A2:Z99
   range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy , ascending:false});
};
```

### References:

[Sheet getRange(row, column, numrows, numcloumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

[Sheet getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

[Sheet getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)